# Struts:404 Page not found Error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, struts

I am trying to build a struts application with basic functionalists. My java servlet class *myAction* just returns success. I have compiled this file successfully and placed the .class file in the classes folder of my project.

My Struts Config XML is as follows:

```
<struts-config>
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/view" type="myAction" validate="false">
            <forward name="success" path="/first.jsp" />
    </action>
    <action path="/view" forward="/view.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

I have a form on view.jsp which has an action path to first.jsp

```
        <form action="first">
        Enter name :
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
    </form>
```

But when I run this code in Tomcat Server and navigate to view.do its working fine. And when I press the submit button of the form, the page is not getting redirected to first.jsp. Instead of first.do,the browser url is navigating to: `**http://localhost:8080/MyProj/first?name=asdf**`.

I am trying to debug this for past two days, but no improvement. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where's the "first" action declared? Have you considered going through a tutorial or the docs?

Comment: you missed to configure the action that u r calling on submit from your jsp.

Comment: I am sorry I might missed the action for "first.jsp" over here but i have given it in the struts-config.xml as follows "<action path="/first"
    forward="/first.jsp"/>" ..still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

404 is the common error occurred  When  client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested.

Here the url, you trying to invoke seems to be invalid. Action path is the url path to access the page. And when you click on submit on the "First" jsp page, it points to the /first action path in the struts-config.xml

please check whether you have properly deployed and make the necessary configuration changes.

It works, if your rest of the configuration are correct.

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProj/view.do
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have form action of 'first' and there is no mapping found in struts-config.xml. I assume that on click of submit button, you wanted to go to myAction and returns to 'first.jsp'. Update '/view' to '/first' as follows and check.

```
<action path="/first" type="myAction" validate="false">
            <forward name="success" path="/first.jsp" />
</action>
```

Also, change action to 'first.do':

```
<form action="first.do">
        Enter name :
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: <action path="/first"
    forward="/first.jsp"/> ...i had included this in the struts-config.xml file but still i am getting the error.

Comment: you should have `<form action="first.do">` if you have *.do as url-pattern.

Comment: but if I want to implement a java class, then how should my action path be?

Comment: your action path can same as i have mentioned `<action path="/first" type="myAction" validate="false">
            <forward name="success" path="/first.jsp" />
</action>`. type declares your java class